# Issue importing DirectUpload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am trying to trigger a direct upload via Javascript in my Rails app.

I am putting this at the top of the script in my view:

> import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage"

and get this error:

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a   module

Can anyone tell me where I should put the import statement.  I am using the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import `DirectUpload`, you should to use webpacker.
When using the asset pipeline, you need to `//= require activestorage`. `DirectUpload` will then be available via `new ActiveStorage.DirectUpload()`.